# Determinant of a $2k\times 2k$ matrix with zero diagonal and $+1$ and $-1$ off the diagonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that the determinant of a $2k\times 2k$ matrix with zero diagonal and $+1$ and $−1$ off diagonal entries (with no particular order) is non-zero in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. What can we say about such a matrix in other fields (particularly, is there any field in which the determinant is zero)?

Comment: If you are working in (a field of) characteristic zero, the determinant is an integer.  So the answer "in $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$" will be the same integer.  That leaves finite fields (positive characteristic) as a possibility where the determinant is zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any even $n$, let $X$ be the collection of $n \times n$ matrices with off-diagonal entries $\pm 1$ and diagonal entries $0$. In particular, the matrix $B = (b_{ij})$ with off-diagonal entries $1$ and diagonal entries $0$ belongs to $X$. It is easy to show $\det(B) = (n-1)(-1)^{n-1}$.

For any $A = (a_{ij}) \in X$, we have $a_{ij} \equiv b_{ij} \pmod 2$ for $i, j$.  This implies

$$\det(A) \equiv \det(B) = (n-1)(-1)^n \equiv 1 \pmod 2\quad\implies\quad\det(A) \ne 0$$

Not sure what happens in general. However, if $p$ is prime factor of $n-1$,
then $\det(B) = 0$ on any field with characteristic $p$.

Comment: I believe this answer is wrong. see for example https://matrixcalc.org/en/det.html#determinant-Gauss%28%7B%7B0,1,1,1,1%7D,%7B1,0,1,1,1%7D,%7B1,1,0,1,-1%7D,%7B-1,1,1,0,1%7D,%7B1,1,1,1,0%7D%7D%29

Comment: @one the dimension of your determinant is $5$, an odd number.

Comment: my bad, you're right. would you mind explaining how do we get $\det(A) \equiv \det(B)$ from $a_{ij} \equiv b_{ij} \pmod 2$?

Comment: @one Given any matrix $C = (c_{ij})$ with integer entries, when you change an entry, say $C_{ij}$ to $C'_{ij} = C_{ij} + m$ by an even integer $m$ and expand the $\det C'$ in $m$, you obtain $\det C' = \det C + m* $(some integer), This means $\det C'$ and $\det C$ will either be both even or both odd. Given any $A \in X$, you can turn it into $B$ using this sort of changes, so $\det A$ and $\det B$ will be both even or both odd.